# Classic ASP - passing a property as byref

Tags: properties, asp-classic, pass-by-reference, byref

In Classic ASP, I have an object, call it `bob`. This then has a property called `name`, with `let` and `get` methods.

I have a function as follows:

```
sub append(byref a, b)
    a = a & b
end sub
```

This is simply to make it quicker to add text to a variable. I also have the same for `prepend`, just it is `a = b & a`. I know it would be simple to say `bob.name = bob.name & "andy"`, but I tried using the above functions and neither of them work.

The way I am calling it is `append bob.name, "andy"`. Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

Comment: I also tried this from within `bob`, using `append Title, "andy"`, but it still didn't work. :(

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is a feature of VBScript.  It is documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101(v=vs.84).aspx under "Argument in a class".  The alternative is to use a function.  Here is an example illustrating the difference.  You can run this from the command line using "cscript filename.vbs.

```
sub append (a, b)
   a = a & b
end sub

function Appendix(a, b)
   Appendix = a & b
end function

class ClsAA
   dim m_b
   dim m_a
end class
dim x(20)

a = "alpha"
b = "beta"
wscript.echo "variable works in both cases"
append a, b
wscript.echo "sub " & a
a = appendix(a, b)
wscript.echo "function " & a

x(10) = "delta"
wscript.echo "array works in both cases"
append x(10), b
wscript.echo "sub " & x(10)
x(10) = appendix( x(10), b)
wscript.echo "function " & x(10)

set objAA = new ClsAA
objAA.m_a = "gamma"
wscript.echo "Member only works in a function"
append objAA.m_a, b
wscript.echo "sub " & objAA.m_a
objAA.m_a = appendix(objAA.m_a, b)
wscript.echo "function " & objAA.m_a
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using with the keyword `CALL`:

```
call append (bob.name, "andy")
```

Classic ASP is fickel about ByRef and ByVal.  By default it uses ByRef -- no reason to specify that.  If you call a function with parenthesis (without the call), it will pass the variables as ByVal.

Alternatively, you could accomplish the same with:

```
function append(byref a, b)
    append = a & b
end sub

bob.name = append(bob.name, "andy");
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the first solution didn't work unfortunately. For the 2nd solution, it takes less characters just to append it normally using `bob.name = bob.name & "andy"`; the entire point of this function is to reduce the number of characters by only referencing the variable, that I am appending to, once.

Answer (score 0):

As [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796040/447356) correctly states, you are facing limitation of the language itself.

The only other option to achieve what you are after as far as I can see it, is to add such sub routine to the class itself:

```
Public Sub Append(propName, strValue)
    Dim curValue, newValue
    curValue = Eval("Me." & propName)
    newValue = curValue & strValue
    Execute("Me." & propName & " = """ & Replace(newValue, """", """""") & """")
End Sub
```

Then to use it:

```
bob.Append "name", "andy"
```

Less elegant,  but working.